# How to create this type of slider to open next screen?

Tags: android, slider

I want to create a slider to move through next and previous screen like below image

[image]

I have already implemented swipe feature to the application like if user swipes left or right he/she can move through next and previous screen but how to implement that swiping on particular area of screen and how to have this type of image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) for this.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: This example requires minimum API level is 14

Comment: You can use support package. You don't need to change to API Level 14. Click on the "ViewPager" link above.

Comment: and how do i create this kind of scrollable image ?

Answer (score 0):

this is the work of the following things

1. A background image repeated for the slider background,an image for the lock and unlock,an image for the button selection.
2. Events you need will be as follows

   1. Touch event on the lock image
       Action performed will be a translation of that button to x position of your thumb you can ger the coordinates in the touchevent
      ActionDown will be the place you started the press and up will be the place you realeased it.

So that can help building this slider.

Comment: can you give any example for same ?